# Custom Action in Sharepoint Online Homepage (Modern Experience)

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-actions, aspx, modern-experience

I want to add a Custom Action on the Homepage of my Modern Sharepoint Online Site, the site that I'm talking about is a subsite. I know how to deploy the button on a List or Document type by manipulating the RegistrationID or RegistrationType but I want the button to be visible on the home.aspx page

I want to add the button on the yellow space [image]